# How to use XDocument.CreateWriter method?

Tags: c#, xml

Let's say I have a 3rd party library that produces xml like this (actually, this is a SharePoint project):

```
<webParts>
    <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
        <metaData>
            <type name="SomeType, SomeAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ecb5ce1bdfc30252" />
            <importErrorMessage>Impossible d’importer ce composant WebPart.</importErrorMessage>
        </metaData>
        <data>
            <properties>
                <property name="DataFields" type="string" />
                <property name="XmlDefinitionLink" type="string" />
                <property name="FilterIncludeChildren3" type="bool">False</property>

            </properties>
        </data>
    </webPart>
</webParts>
```

This xml is produce by calling a method that accepts an `XmlTextWriter` argument. As I want to work with an `XDocument` object, I use this code:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
using(var sw = new StringWriter(sb))
using (var xw = new XmlTextWriter(sw))
{
    sourceMgr.ExportWebPart(webPartToClone, xw);
}
var wpAsXml = XDocument.Parse(sb.ToString());
```

This is working as expected. However, to reduce number of line of codes, I also tried this code:

```
var wpAsXml = new XDocument();
sourceMgr.ExportWebPart(webPartToClone, wpAsXml.CreateWriter());
```

But this code fails with the following error:

```
System.Xml.XmlException: The prefix '' cannot be redefined from '' to 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3' within the same start element tag.
   at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.PushNamespace(String prefix, String ns, Boolean explicitlyDefined)
   at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteEndAttribute()
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartManager.ExportWebPart(WebPart webPart, XmlWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.ExportWebPartInternal(WebPart webPart, XmlWriter writer)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartManager.ExportWebPart(WebPart webPart, XmlWriter writer)
   at SomeWhereInMycode
```

Why does the 2nd code snippet not work? What is the proper way of using this method?

PS: using .net 3.5 SP1

Comment: I think this is just a bug in XmlWellFormedWriter, this code was substantially revised in .NET 4.  Good thing you've got a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot recreate the scenario locally; so this is a shot in the dark. It may be a scoping issue try:

```
XNamespace wp = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3";

XDocument wpAsXml = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "true"),
                                  new XElement(wp + "webParts"));       

using (XmlWriter writer = wpAsXml.CreateWriter()) 
{
   sourceMgr.ExportWebPart(webPartToClone, writer);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately the behavior is exactly the same.